# NewtonSoft JArray two levels deep to extract to list in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following code:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var jarr = obj["data"].Value<JArray>();            
List<Person> lst = jarr.ToObject<List<Person>>();
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", lst[0].Name, lst[1].Age);
```

Which works. But I need to go two levels deep in the json now:

```
..."data":[{"moredata":...
```

I am trying the following but it gives me an error:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var jarr = obj["data"]["moredata"].Value<JArray>();  //  This is not working to go two levels deep        
List<Person> lst = jarr.ToObject<List<Person>>();
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", lst[0].Name, lst[1].Age);
```

Any help would be appreciated specifying the correct syntax for line above to go two levels deep in json.

Here is the format of the json data. I would like to remove the whole "moredata" level since it is not part of the Person class:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "moredata": {
                "first_name": "Bob",
                "last_name": "Smith"
            }
        }, {
            "moredata": {
                "first_name": "Albert",
                "last_name": "Rodgers"
            }
        }, {
            "moredata": {
                "first_name": "Dan",
                "last_name": "Anderson"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brian for the suggestion.  I have added the sample json as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your JSON sample, here's how you would get the list of people:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var jarr = obj["data"].Value<JArray>();       
List<Person> lst = jarr.Select(a => a["moredata"].ToObject<Person>()).ToList();
```

In other words, you retrieve the array like you were doing initially.  Then for *each item* in the array you want to go down a level and convert it to a Person.  Then put all of those people into a list.

Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xtp34E

Comment: Thank you Brian, that works perfect.  Beautiful code and example!

Comment: Glad I could help!